# Is 3to2 python backporting valid?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python3 code which I am backporting to python 2. I have used 3to2. there are certain changes which I am not sure of

1. 3to2 is appending u' ' before each string including docstrings,headers, print statements and even while accessing response json from the API.

Eg - requests.get(u'geturl')
Headers[u'Authorization']

Is this valid or they can be simply string?

2. Regarding the 'open' while opening the files, it has been translated as

```
from io import open
f = open(filename, u'rb')
```

Why not use inbuilt open and why the u"" Before the 'rb'

Comment: The equivalent to `"xyz"` in Python 3 is `u"xyz"` in Python 2. `"xyz"` in Python 2 would be `b"xyz"` in Python 3.